# Heroku App custom domain, forwarding from goDaddy & getting different behavior for `www.example.com` vs `example.com`

Tags: godaddy, cname, domain-forwarding, heroku

I have deployed an app on heroku - `http://appsparkler.heroku.com` and created a custom domain for it - `www.appsparkler.com`

Then, from `goDaddy`, where I have purchased this domain name `appsparkler.com`, I `forward with masking` to `http://appsparkler.heroku.com` and redirect `301 (Permanent)`. Screenshot

[image]

Then, I made changes to the `DNS ZONE FILE` where I added `CNAME` and `A Host` as per a blog I found on the internet.

[image]

[image]

This works fine and when I visit `www.appsparkler.com` I am redirected with `masking` and can also visit the various links with the `URL` changing to the link I click on.  However, when I browse the webapp with `appsparkler.com` i.e. without the `www`, I can go to the various links; however, the links in the address bar don't get updated.  For comparision,  I have added screenshot of `address bar` when on `home` page, first with `www.appsparkler.com` and then with `appsparkler.com`.  We can see that `/home` doesn't reflect in second one.  Moreover, even the `favicon.ico` doesn't appear in the second one **(without www)** as we can see...

[image]

[image]

I have tried searching a lot and also tried trial and errors with different settings and looked for solutions on the web and nothing worked.

Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was going to suggest that perhaps the problem was the "with masking" bit? (I would have thought `example.com` should just be an external redirect to `www.example.com` and then the CNAME record in DNS directs the request to the heroku server?) But you appear to have already solved it - how did you solve it?

Comment: Please check the answer in the answer section.  I figured it after re-configuring as per instructions on http://lifesforlearning.com/heroku-with-godaddy/.  And also what you have suggested in the comment is what fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference http://lifesforlearning.com/heroku-with-godaddy/

In the `FORWARD AND MASKING` section (which is under `SETTINGS` >> `Forwarding`), I was `forward(ing) with masking` (as you can see in the screenshot in the question above)  to the `herokuapp` >> `http://appsparkler.herokuapp.com`.  I changed that to `forward`(without masking) to `http://www.appsparkler.com` as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]